# IMAGEREL operator in Intel c X64 inline asm

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly, icc

I'm using Intel c X64 inline asm to compile some assembly code, array of data are accessed like below:

```
int buf[100];
-------------------------------------------------
_asm
{
lea rax, __ImageBase
mov rcx, 10
mov [IMAGEREL buf+rax+rcx*8], 0x1234
}
```

ICC complains about IMAGEREL keyword, ml64 compiles this fine, does ICC have any equivalent for IMAGEREL keyword;

PS: I know I can use the below addressing mode as well, but this gonna need tons of changes to my code:

```
_asm
{
lea rax, buf
mov rcx, 10
mov [rax+rcx*8], 0x1234
}
```

thanks

PS: I used -S switch to generate asm listing for some c code, in the output I found asm code like this, but when I put it in inline asm, ICC complains about imagerel operator

```
movdqu xmmword ptr [imagerel(buf) + rcx + rdx * 4], xmm0
```

Comment: Please explain how C **and** C++ come into this.

Comment: my first post on this site, sorry if I tagged this wrong, question is about Intel c compiler, so I figured...

Comment: have you tried to declare IMGREL as an empty macro ?

Comment: IMAGEREL is supposed to return RVA [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177476.aspx), defining it as empty macro will ruin code execution!

Comment: Your `IMAGEREL` code works in MSVC, right?  Or as stand-alone asm files I guess, because MSVC dropped inline asm for x86-64?  It sounds like you have an existing codebase using it, and you want to port that to *inline* asm?

Comment: you're right, about 45% of my code is in asm files, ml64 compiles them happily, I'm trying to port them to inline asm, in order to debug\change\convert to c